# Redirect All Link after the Character

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to know how to redirect all the links with random character after the main link
for example I have a link which is a categorythat has 10 products

http://www.doamin.com/index.php?cPath=1RandomVarailable10

http://www.domain.com/index.php?cPath=1_2RandomVarailable10

so what I did is

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.newdomain1.com [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=1_2
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.newdomain2.com [R=301,L]
```

but is not working/conflicting each other

Comment: What is your intended purpose?

Comment: redirect all link which is under a path url or category
example domain.com/cpath_1    then redirect all link  under it domain.com/cpath_1/productids, domain.com/cpath_1/tags,  domain.com/cpath_1&codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `?` to get rid of the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.newdomain.com/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cPath=1_2
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.newdomain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i have updated the question, the redirect has two different path